# What is being done in all this non-rpc time for a fetch?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Say I have some model Object, and ~2000 entities in my datastore. Using app stats with the following code

```
ndb.get_context().set_cache_policy(lambda x: False)
ndb.get_context().set_memcache_policy(lambda x: False)
objects = Object.query().fetch()
```

I get the following profile

[image: Query profile]

What is being done for the ~18 seconds that it's not waiting for RPCs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely deserializing those entities into python objects and the process is **very very slow**. You shouldn't be fetching that many entities during a single web request from a client anyway and if it's for some kind of a batch job - the time shouldn't matter that much (note also that once you go over several thousand items - your requests will likely time out at some point so you will need to use something like [query cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#cursors)).

You may also find [this](http://mattfaus.com/2014/12/speeding-up-gae-datastore-reads-with-protobuf-projection/) and [this](http://www.evanjones.ca/app-engine-db-serialization.html) blog posts helpful on some hacks to speed the deserialization process up.

Also, unrelated but this is one of the many cases where Golang would shine and way outperform Python on the exact same task (that delay would be almost non-existent).

Comment: One way of cutting down these delays would thus be to choose a faster instance class (at extra cost).